# likelihood for regression purposes

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood

Which role plays [likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) in regression analysis? I've seen it [here](https://medium.com/quick-code/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-regression-65f9c99f815d), but I can't figure out when I exactly have to use it. Is it, when I know which function or model I want to apply (which I know via R-squared for example), then I perform MLE to get the best parameters for this selected model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first you have to agree on the *model*, because that fixes your parameter set and how they're related. In regression analysis, maximum likelihood (ML) is a perspective to look at the problem. The end-formula in the medium article you've linked can be derived in various ways (such as via an [*optimization* formulation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ordinary_least_squares) with MSE as objective function to minimize). ML introduces a probabilistic perspective to the analysis and enables us to interpret and maybe change the underlying distributions (of the noise, and/or covariates) to reach different conclusions.

Comment: Thank you very much! To ensure: OLS is applied on MLE to get the best parameters?

Comment: OLS and MLE are different interpretations trying to achieve the same goal: finding best parameters.

Comment: thanks again! The same applies to chi-squared, right? Thus, chi-squared, ols and mle are tools for the same purpose?

Comment: if you mean chi-squared test, it is for evaluating the model, not finding best parameters.

Comment: but reduced chi-square is for fitting, right?

Comment: is it? Does it estimate $\beta$? https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic

Comment: Good question, but in the link you provide, they write "a chi-squared>1 indicates a poor model fit"

Comment: goodness of fit is different than parameter estimation though. It's some sort of an evaluation of your model.

Comment: Ok, but nevertheless, reduced chi-squared is used for fitting?

Comment: if we condider evaluating a model with estimated parameters as a part of fitting, yes.